# How to get value that is associated with another value in R

Tags: r, sorting, indexing

I have a dataframe (dt) that looks like this:

```
Color    X2     
Red      2      
Blue     NA    
Green    1
```

Below is my code. When I use this function, it outputs `1` as the answer. However, I want it to say `Green` ( the value associated with the SECOND most hits (1).) Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

```
Function <-function(MostHits) {
Res <- sort(dt$X2, TRUE)[2]
print(Res)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reference the right element of `Color`

```
Function <-function(MostHits) {
   Res <- dt$Color[order(dt$X2, decreasing=TRUE)[2]]
   print(Res)
}  
Function()
[1] Green
```

But why do you include the spurious argument `MostHits`?   Why not just
`Function <-function() { ...`
Or did you mean
`MostHits <- function() { ...`